# How to use the gamma distribution equation

Tags: r, glm, gamma

I am using R to fit a GLM with Gamma distribution (link inverse). I would like to use the equation of the model to get other values of my predictors, knowing the response value. I know that the equation of a gamma distribution with link inverse is 1/μ = b0 + b1x1i, can you confirm that I should substitute to μ the mean of my response value?